# What to choose fsyacc/fslex or FParsec?

Tags: f#, fsyacc, fslex, fparsec

I need to parse simple DSL language like the following:

```
import "library.txt"

def <int, bool, byte> main(int param1, bool param2)
{
    var a = f4(param1); // or var d = f1(f2(f3(f4(param1))));
    var b = f3(a);
    var c = f2(b);
    var d = f1(c);

    return <d, param2, b0>;
}
```

What is the most suitable tool to parse such kind of language?

Comment: If you go with FsYaac/FsLex then I highly recommend the [F# Parsed Language Starter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a075ff98-7e6f-47ce-a23c-838c1e488046/) template - it avoids having to play around with the command prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lex/Yacc are usually better for complete languages with complicated grammars. Parsec is faster to work with when you have short semi-simple tasks. I think that for your case, Lex/Yacc would be much more suitable.

Answer (score 4):

You might find [this bullet-point comparison](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/about/fparsec-vs-alternatives.html) of FParsec with parser generator tools (e.g. fslex & fsyacc) and "hand‐written" recursive descent parsers useful for choosing between the available alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most suitable tool to parse such kind of language?

I would use active patterns.